# Getting unique hit count in php

Tags: php, mysql, database, counter

I want to add a unique hit counter to my website using PHP. This counter will save visitor's IP for each page in a database. I have a database structure like this:

Table `hits` with two columns:

```
ip
page_url
```

My question is: after getting the visitor's IP in a PHP file, which is better (for performance)?

1. To check if the IP address is already in the database. And when not already in the database add it
2. Just add all visitors IPs (without duplicate check) and then get distinct IPs for relevant page to get the unique hit count?

Comment: For performance, it is better to parse apache's access log later, possibly even on other servers, and let the count lag somewhat, rather then trying to keep up with requests.

Comment: I have just 1 server. And the trafic of  my site is not very much.

Comment: In that case, just create a `UNIQUE` index on `(ip,page_url)`, and do an `INSERT IGNORE ...`

Comment: hmm, thanks very much. it would not be cause error ?

Comment: Avoid unnecessary indices on write-heavy tables! Use the primary instead.

Comment: If it's the only data in there, yes, by all means, make it the primary.

Comment: I elaborated in my answer. Short version: Make the combination of ip and page_url the primary key, not an additional unique key.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are on MySQL you might want to abuse the combination of PRIMARY KEY and ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE:

```
CREATE TABLE hits (
ip VARCHAR(15),
page_url VARCHAR(200),
PRIMARY KEY (ip,page_url),
hitcount INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
)
```

Now on a page hit you do

```
INSERT INTO hits(ip, page_url,hitcount) VALUES('$ip','$url',1)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE hitcount=hitcount+1
```

Why this?

- Another unique key is POISON for a write-heavy table, so avoid it.
  Really.
- INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE only locks the row once

You may also want to record the timestamp of last access:

```
ALTER TABLE hits ADD COLUMN lastseen TIMESTAMP();
```

Comment: I also favor the timestamp field.  (You could make it auto-update as well, or add two timestamp fields:  firstseen and lastseen)

Comment: My Version is auto-updating: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/timestamp.html says "With neither DEFAULT nor ON UPDATE clauses, it is the same as DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP."

Comment: OH NO! now I checked this code. it count for different IPs and it doesn't count unique hits. I need the query which count unique hits for page. I mean, I need the count of different IPs for relevant page

Comment: If you got the table definition right, this is not possible: the ip is part of the primary key! Post your "SHOW CREATE TABLE hits"

Comment: My hits table as the same as you post. I have "pages" table too. Isn't it possible to add "unique_hits" column to "pages" table, then write the query which update"unique_hits" if posted IP not found in hits table for relevant page ?

Comment: THis is a different question: your hits table will have a row for every (unique) ip accessing a (unique) url. If you want the unique hits on a page, do "SELECT page_url, count(*) AS distincthits, SUM(hitcount) as totalhits FROM hits"

Comment: oh, yes. thanks, it may be useful for me. but is it possible to do this process without SELECT command, just with UPDATE command with another data structure ? if yes, then how? because I think selecting count of rows everytime is not good way for performance.

Comment: You do the SELECT only if you create your hits record! Not on every page access.

Comment: yeah, I know. I need another variant with another data structure without selecting all rows (because, the count rows is so much). i will be glad, if you help me. I want the algorithm to do this process  without selecting all rows.

Comment: btw, I know it's another question :)

Answer (score 2):

Presuming you're comfortable with simple programming.

**NOT TRULY "REAL TIME" BUT ALMOST REAL TIME**
Highly recommend you to write out to a log with your own format to a text file (if you're not comfortable with Apache's `[customlog][1]` feature).

Then, set up a cronjob every 5 minutes, or even once every 1 minute if you want close to "live", import the text into a MySql temporary table in a big gulp with `LOAD DATA INFILE` and then update your visitcounts table based on GROUP BY ip.

**FULLY REAL TIME**
This can be a huge drag on your server but given that you have light traffic just create two tables in MySQL. One just records the article/page ID being read + IP + time (log table). The other contains article/page ID and visit counts--where the counts are updated GROUP BY ip in the first table.

Answer (score 2):

with the help of [Eugen Rieck](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1100552/eugen-rieck) I made my code with time and date store.

In this code, it store user ip, count,date and time.

```html
$ipaddress = '';
    if (getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP'))
        $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP');
    else if(getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'))
        $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR');
    else if(getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED'))
        $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED');
    else if(getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR'))
        $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR');
    else if(getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED'))
        $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED');
    else if(getenv('REMOTE_ADDR'))
        $ipaddress = getenv('REMOTE_ADDR');
    else
$ipaddress = 'UNKNOWN'; // final ip address
$time=date("Y/m/d H:i:s"); // date and time in a single variable
$sql = "INSERT IGNORE INTO `ipaddress` (`id`, `ipaddress`, `count`, `time`) VALUES ('', '$ipaddress','1', '$time') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE count=count+1, time='".$time."'"; // adding ip,count, date and time to table
if($conn->query($sql) === false) {
  trigger_error('Wrong SQL: ' . $sql . ' Error: ' . $conn->error, E_USER_ERROR);
} else {

  $last_inserted_id = $conn->insert_id;
  $affected_rows = $conn->affected_rows;
}

$conn->close();
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use unique key on (`ip`, `page_url`), optionally `date`. If the record isn't there it would be create, it would cause error otherwise (but you can easily check error code) or you could use `IGNORE` in `INSERT` statement..

It'd take only one request to the database and would be probably the fastest. You would have also automatically guaranteed that all records will be unique and you wouldn't need to use a transaction.

Answer (score 0):

Hi john and fellow flow peeps... I'm new to programming and MYSQL, ...however the way I got round it was the following:

I use some PHP code to query the hits DB and then evaluate both columns, `ip` and `page_url` and if they evaluate to true do nothing, else *...insert/execute the code shown above by Eugene Rick...*

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; // Get IP Address.

$purl = htmlspecialchars($_GET['page_url']); // Get Page URL.

$results = $mysqli->query("select * from hits"); // Query hits table.

$row = $results->fetch_assoc(); // Fetch array and assign to $row, then evaluate with if statement.

if ($row['ip'] == $ip && $row['page_url'] == $purl) {

} else {
    $mysqli->query("insert into hits (ip,page_url,counter) values ('$ip','$purl',1) on duplicate key update counter=counter+1");
}
```

I'll be honest I have not checked this on more than one IP address, just mine.

However it adds rows to the hits table for each URL inserted based on an unique ip (the one I'm currently using) and does not increment the hits count for any inserted URL when the page is refreshed so I assume it works...